# Deployment of MVC-PHP code on docker container and accessing through browser

Tags: php, docker, model-view-controller

We have a docker container already set up/built, I now need to point so that it loads php pages in a browser, so it gets its own docker folder with httpdocs and our files inside. But it's not pointing so we get 404 errors. We use Centos7 and the php version is normally my files eg website and portals are in: httpdocs.
but here we set up a new folder for the docker container. You should tell me where to put the container
if you get index.php to load or a test file hello world the rest should be fine
I think pointing is the issue
the container does NOT include our website...no reason for this..it's for our portals

The path is:
/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dockerPHP
okay
then we have:
dockerPHP/dump (where we put our DB)
dockerPHP/httpdocs (for our files)
dockerPHP/www (currently empty)
top level files:
dockerPHP/docker-compose-yml and dockerFile

Now on the apache/linux server we have our portals running nicely under httpdocs.
The only change is a docker container needs to point/so that eg index.php shows in a browser.

FROM php:7.1.19-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring

please help
thank you some much in advance

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking and when I got to *okay ma'am like we can run on apache* I gave up.

Comment: sorry my bad, so in brief, i want to run a mvc-php application on docker and access through a browser, can it be done!?

Comment: Of course PHP applications can be run inside of docker.
But maybe you should start reading a tutorial?
Your question is kind of confusing.

Comment: @Pampy i mean i have tried this normal method like hosting in var/www/html and started apache server and i have excuted with docker run 8080:8080 command

Comment: @Pampy can you tell how can we run it please